# Proof that $|(0,1)| = |(0,1)^{\mathbb{N}}|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to understand a proof from my professor's lecture notes arguing that $|(0,1)| = |(0,1)^{\mathbb{N}}|$. Here is my understanding of the proof, with some additional detail added by me.

> Define the map $(0,1) \to (0,1)^{\mathbb{N}}$ sending $x = 0.a_1 a_2 a_3 \ldots$, written without terminating in an infinite string of nines, to the sequence $(s_1, s_2, s_3, \ldots)$, where $s_k$, by definition, takes the first available digit after the decimal point that hasn't already been enumerated in $s_1, \ldots, s_{k-1}$ and then increments by $2^k$. For example,
> \begin{align*}
> s_1 & = a_1 a_3 a_5 a_7 a_9 \ldots \\
> s_2 & = a_2 a_6 a_{10} a_{14} \ldots \\
> s_3 & = a_4 a_{12} a_{20} a_{28} \ldots \\
> & \vdots \\
> \end{align*}
> This mapping is well-defined since we use the decimal expansion of $x$ not terminating in an infinite sequence of $9$'s, which we know to be unique, and it's a bijection because it is invertible. Namely, given a sequence $(s_1, s_2, s_3, \ldots)$, using the above construction, we can uniquely determination $x = 0.a_1 a_2 a_3 \ldots$.

How does this look?  The proof of bijectivity seems somewhat frail to me, though it does seem simple to me to reconstruct $x$. The assertion that this decimal expansion is unique, while true, also seems a bit flimsy to me; if anyone can give a hint on how to prove that, this would be helpful.

Comment: Notice that $x=\frac9{22}=0.4090909…$ and $y=\frac12=0.500000…$ map to the same sequence $\langle\frac12, 0,0,0,…\rangle$. I think this could be fixed.

Comment: I didn't realize this. Do you have a suggestion for how to fix this?

Comment: Note also that, as per MJD's example, the range is slightly greater than $(0,1)^\mathbb{N}$; in fact, $[0,1]^\mathbb{N} \backslash \{0\}^\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I think you can fix some of the problems by defining $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ not to be single digits, but to be _chunks_ of digits consisting of zero or more nines followed by a digit other than 9.  For example, when $x=0.4090909\ldots$, instead of $a_i = \langle 4, 0, 9, 0, 9, \ldots\rangle$, we make $a_i = \langle 4, 0, 90, 90, 90, 90\ldots\rangle$.   Then everything else proceeds the same way. This at least fixes my example.